# limitations to serial port Asynchroneous Input function?

Tags: linux, embedded, serial-port

We have a Linux embedded project and we are concerned with performance.

The Serial port Asynchronous Input example at:
http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-HOWTO/Serial-Programming-HOWTO.html#AEN105
pretty much does what we want.

However the engineer in charge objects to the CPU performance lost by the 
looped sleep call. He would like the program to wait for a signal to execute the response handling code instead.

I tried moving that code from main() to inside the signal function, i.e.:

```
void signal_handler_IO (int status)
{
    // I moved my code here
}
```

The result does not work, writes to the serial port made in that function quickly fail and the program becomes completely unresponsive.

Why is that?

And does anyone have a good online example of Signal-Driven I/O for just one serial port? I have been poring over Chapter 63 of Kerrisk's "The Linux Priogramming Interface" book and googling like crazy. I am beginning to think there might not be a better way to do the initial example.

Thanks in advance,

Bert

Comment: See the comment "normally we would do something useful here".  Don't setup non-blocking I/O and then call sleep, setup non-blocking I/O and then do something useful in that thread, like all of the rest of your functionality if you prefer to have a single threaded application.  Otherwise, if you want to go multi threaded dedicate a thread to watching the serial and use blocking I/O so the kernel will suspend the thread until there's something for it to do.  Or have an I/O thread that uses select to watch multiple input sources and only gets woken up when there's input on one of them.

Comment: In general, it's a bad idea to ask two separate questions ("Why is that?" and "does anyone have an example?") in the same question.  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts.

Answer (score 1):

If you are worried about waking up regularly from the `usleep()` call when there is no input available, simply replace the `usleep()` call with a `pause()`, that will suspend your process until the SIGIO occurs.

Answer (score 0):

In general, doing anything complicated (i.e., touches things beyond the immediate stack) in a signal handler is dangerous -- see http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Nonreentrancy.html for a fairly thorough description.  I/O operations are particularly unsafe, as they tend to do allocations and poking of hardware and such.

If you don't like the explicit wait loop, you might try using semaphores -- see
http://linux.die.net/man/7/sem_overview for details.  In particular, `sem_post` is explicitly documented as safe for use in signal handlers, so you can put a (blocking) call to `sem_wait` in your read loop in place of the `usleep`, and then unblock it by calling `sem_post` in your signal handler.